# C# DataTable Date format in query

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, datatable, oledb

To start with, I would like to point out that I know to avoid using a string directly from a TextBox or DatePicker in an SQL query as is shown in the code below.  After I figure out how to make this work I intend to fix all of those, but for simplicity while initially coding and testing, I am using it for now.  I point this out because everything I've found on Google points that out, but then doesn't seem to give an actual answer to the real question. :)  That being said, here goes...

I have an Access 2010 database (.accdb) that I need to read data from in order to fill multiple TextBoxes in WPF.  No matter how I format the Date in the query, I get an Exception of one kind or another.  The code I've been using is:

```
    public void UpdateEarlyStageData(string filePath, string query)
    {
        List<string> departments = new List<string>();

        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
            @"User Id=;Password=;";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(table);

                    massCellRecords.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellRecords"].ToString();
                    massCellDials.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellDials"].ToString();
                    massCellSaturation.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellSaturation"].ToString();
                    massCellPercentTotal.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellPercentVolume"].ToString();
                    massCellPercentWorked.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellPassPenetration"].ToString();
                    massCellPassPercent.Text = table.Rows[0]["MASSCellTotalPassPenFactor"].ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }

    private void recordDateES_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        string filePath = "C:\\Dialer Team Back-End Database\\DialerTeam_be.accdb";
        DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Parse(recordDateES.ToString());
        //string queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "#";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #" + targetDate.ToShortDateString() + "#";
        //queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #" + targetDate + "#";
        queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #05//02//2016#";

        UpdateEarlyStageData(filePath, queryString);
    }
```

The exceptions I've seen are:

**InvalidOperationException:  The provider could not determine the Double value.**

This one happens when I format the query as `queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #05/02/2016#";`.  I assume what's happening here is it's trying to divide 05 by 02, and that result by 2016.

**OleDbException:  Syntax error in date in query expression 'CallDate = #05//02//2016'**

This one happens when I format the query as `queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #05//02//2016#";`.  I don't know why this would be the case, as I have other queries that use this format, the only difference is that they aren't using a DataTable but rather just a direct `OleDbDataReader`.

Each of the commented-out lines in the code above reflects various attempts to make this work but none of them works...please help!

**UPDATE:**
I haven't found a solution or answer to this exactly, but I do have working code that accomplishes the same thing.  Rather than use a DataTable, I'm just using an OleDbConnection directly.  As this isn't really a solution to the question asked, I don't think this is really an answer per se, so I'm just going to paste the code below so that anyone having a similar issue in the future can reference this.

```
    private void saveData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (departmentSelector.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            string query = "";
            string filePath = "C:\\Dialer Team Back-End Database\\DialerTeam_be.accdb";
            DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Parse(recordDateES.ToString());

            string massCellString = "MASSCellRecords = @massCellRecords, MASSCellDials = @massCellDials, MASSCellSaturation = @massCellSaturation," +
                " MASSCellPercentVolume = @massCellPercentVolume, MASSCellPassPenetration = @massCellPassPenetration, MASSCellTotalPassPenFactor =  @massCellTotalPassPenFactor";
            string miCellString = "MICellRecords = @miCellRecords, MICellDials = @miCellDials, MICellSaturation = @miCellSaturation," +
                " MICellPercentVolume = @miCellPercentVolume, MICellPassPenetration = @miCellPassPenetration, MICellTotalPassPenFactor =  @miCellTotalPassPenFactor";
            string allString = "AllRecords = @allRecords, AllDials = @allDials, AllSaturation = @allSaturation," +
                " AllPercentVolume = @allPercentVolume, AllPassPenetration = @allPassPenetrationOne, AllTotalPassPenFactor =  @allTotalPassPenFactorOne," +
                " AllPassPenetrationTwo = @allPassPenetrationTwo, AllTotalPassPenFactorTwo =  @allTotalPassPenFactorTwo," +
                " AllPassPenetrationThree = @allPassPenetrationThree, AllTotalPassPenFactorThree =  @allTotalPassPenFactorThree";
            string massString = "MASSRecords = @massRecords, MASSDials = @massDials, MASSSaturation = @massSaturation," +
                " MASSPercentVolume = @massPercentVolume, MASSPassPenetration = @massPassPenetration, MASSTotalPassPenFactor =  @massTotalPassPenFactor";
            string nhString = "NHRecords = @nhRecords, NHDials = @nhDials, NHSaturation = @nhSaturation," +
                " NHPercentVolume = @nhPercentVolume, NHPassPenetration = @nhPassPenetration, NHTotalPassPenFactor =  @nhTotalPassPenFactor";
            string nonContString = "NonContRecords = @nonContRecords, NonContDials = @nonContDials, NonContSaturation = @nonContSaturation," +
                " NonContPercentVolume = @nonContPercentVolume, NonContPassPenetration = @nonContPassPenetration, NonContTotalPassPenFactor =  @nonContTotalPassPenFactor";
            string orString = "ORRecords = @orRecords, ORDials = @orDials, ORSaturation = @orSaturation," +
                " ORPercentVolume = @orPercentVolume, ORPassPenetration = @orPassPenetration, ORTotalPassPenFactor =  @orTotalPassPenFactor";
            string combinedString = "CombinedRecords = @combinedRecords, CombinedDials = @combinedDials, CombinedSaturation = @combinedSaturation," +
                " CombinedPassPenetration = @combinedPercentWorkedOne," +
                " CombinedPassPenetrationTwo = @combinedPercentWorkedTwo," +
                " CombinedPassPenetrationThree =  @combinedPercentWorkedThree";

            query = "UPDATE ESDialsPerList SET " + massCellString + ", " + miCellString + ", " + allString + ", " + massString + ", " +
                nhString + ", " + nonContString + ", " + orString + ", " + combinedString +
                " WHERE CallDate = #" + targetDate.ToString() + "#";

            WriteEarlyStageData(filePath, query);
        }
        else if (departmentSelector.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {

        }
        else if (departmentSelector.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {

        }
    }

    public void WriteEarlyStageData(string filePath, string query)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
            @"User Id=;Password=;";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellRecords", Int32.Parse(massCellRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellDials", Int32.Parse(massCellDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellSaturation", Double.Parse(massCellSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellPercentVolume", Double.Parse(massCellPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellPassPenetration", Double.Parse(massCellPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massCellTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(massCellPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellRecords", Int32.Parse(miCellRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellDials", Int32.Parse(miCellDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellSaturation", Double.Parse(miCellSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellPercentVolume", Double.Parse(miCellPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellPassPenetration", Double.Parse(miCellPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miCellTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(miCellPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allRecords", Int32.Parse(allRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allDials", Int32.Parse(allDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allSaturation", Double.Parse(allSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allPercentVolume", Double.Parse(allPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allPassPenetrationOne", Double.Parse(allPercentWorkedOne.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allTotalPassPenFactorOne", Double.Parse(allPassPercentOne.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allPassPenetrationTwo", Double.Parse(allPercentWorkedTwo.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allTotalPassPenFactorTwo", Double.Parse(allPassPercentTwo.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allPassPenetrationThree", Double.Parse(allPercentWorkedThree.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allTotalPassPenFactorThree", Double.Parse(allPassPercentThree.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massRecords", Int32.Parse(massRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massDials", Int32.Parse(massDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massSaturation", Double.Parse(massSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massPercentVolume", Double.Parse(massPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massPassPenetration", Double.Parse(massPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@massTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(massPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhRecords", Int32.Parse(nhRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhDials", Int32.Parse(nhDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhSaturation", Double.Parse(nhSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhPercentVolume", Double.Parse(nhPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhPassPenetration", Double.Parse(nhPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(nhPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContRecords", Int32.Parse(nonContRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContDials", Int32.Parse(nonContDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContSaturation", Double.Parse(nonContSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContPercentVolume", Double.Parse(nonContPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContPassPenetration", Double.Parse(nonContPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nonContTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(nonContPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orRecords", Int32.Parse(orRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orDials", Int32.Parse(orDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orSaturation", Double.Parse(orSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orPercentVolume", Double.Parse(orPercentTotal.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orPassPenetration", Double.Parse(orPercentWorked.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orTotalPassPenFactor", Double.Parse(orPassPercent.Text));

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedRecords", Int32.Parse(combinedRecords.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedDials", Int32.Parse(combinedDials.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedSaturation", Double.Parse(combinedSaturation.Text.Replace("%","")));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedPercentWorkedOne", Double.Parse(combinedPercentWorkedOne.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedPercentWorkedTwo", Double.Parse(combinedPercentWorkedTwo.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combinedPercentWorkedThree", Double.Parse(combinedPercentWorkedThree.Text));

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();                    

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what value do you get in targetDate.ToShortDateString() ?

Comment: have you run the same query within Access DB itself? This enables you determine the format Access expects a date column to be.

Comment: I have done this in Access, and the format expected is #05/02/2016#.  The reason for all of this is I'm converting an existing Access database with VBA over to be used with a C# front-end.

As for the value of targetDate.ToShortDateString(), it gives `5/2/2016`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a parameterised query?

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = @callDate";
OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString);
oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@callDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = targetDate;
```

And a small change in the method signature too to accept an OleDbCommand  instead for a string

```
public void UpdateEarlyStageData(string filePath, OleDbCommand queryCommand)
{
    //Connection string initializer
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        queryCommand.Connection = connection;
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryCommand))
        {
            System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            // assignment operations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work, it gives the same InvalidOperation Exception as above.  I tried putting both a DateTime variable in for `targetDate` and a string converted to `ToShortDateString()`, and both had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to force a non-localized format when converting the date value to a string expression:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM ESDialsPerList WHERE CallDate = #" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
    string
```

The result string will be `#2016/05/02#` which Access SQL accepts.

Comment: Access would also accept `#05/02/2016#` which is, in fact, the preferred notation. Try this out for yourself by pasting `#2016/05/02#` (better: ISO notation #2016-05-02#)  in a VBA module, it will auto-correct to `#5/2/2016#`. The OP's problem, however, might be caused by the provider not understanding the labels Access uses for dates, so all of this might miss the point after all.

Comment: This does result in the same issues, InvalidOperationException if done exactly as posted above, OleDbException if I add the additional slashes to avoid the "division".

Comment: Then your issue is probably related to something else.